# Error:No rule to make target `/usr/local/lib/libboost_unit_test_framework.a'

Tags: thrift

Tried to compile thrift 0.8 in my laptop(ubuntu 11.10 64bit),got this error.Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 4):

in centOs 7:

libboost_unit_test_framework.a is a static lib .

you need to install a static boost lib:

yum install boost-devel-static

Answer (score 2):

Have you installed libboost-test-dev? Try doing so:

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-test-dev
```

Optionally, you can also install all other dev libraries included in Boost:

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-dev
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution investigatng a similar issue with thrift 1.0.0-dev on debian jessie armhf:

Set a softlink to libboost_unit_test_framework.a to complete the build.
See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT-3327

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Magicprog.fr: It actually answers the question. Sometimes, recommending deletion in the VLQQ is wrong...

Answer (score 2):

For Fedora 26 I had to install boost-static

```
sudo dnf install boost-static
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using a Debian system, but I was able to finish compiling thrift by using the following command.

```
$ sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libboost_unit_test_framework.a /usr/local/lib/libboost_unit_test_framework.a
```

The problem was that the following command from http://thrift.apache.org/docs/BuildingFromSource/ for configuring didn't affect one of the libs, and it was looking in `/usr/lib/local` instead of `/usr/local`.

```
$ ./configure --with-boost=/usr/local
```

That first command creates a symlink so that the library can be accessed at either path.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to compile CodeCompass on Debian Jessie, the following solution worked for me. I was running it from withint the `CodeCompass/scripts` dir. You may need to adjust your paths, etc.

```
sudo apt-get install -y libboost-test-dev
ln -sv /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_unit_test_framework.a ../../CodeCompass-deps/lib64/
```